# how to change the sorting direction in sortchange of EXT

Tags: javascript, extjs, header, extjs4, columnsorting

i am using 4.2 EXT , and i have to use sortchange listener to handle the columns sorting , because i some of the columns showing value by rendering .

So i have to handle sorting in sortchange , it work perfectly when i click the sorting icon at the menu in header (ASC/DESC) , but when i click the header to sorting ,the sorting direction always show "ASC" every time .

**All i want is both clicking the sorting icon and clicking the header can sort normally**

i checked my code , i didnt set any default sorting with "ASC" value tho.

i made an example in fiddle , please visit her

Click [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2vfv&view/editor)!

i found out that if i remove the  grid.store.sort({
                            sorterFn : sortingDate,
                            direction : dir
                        }); the correct direction will be shown , but i have to use this method to sorting

```
          var panel = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    id : "Panel",
    store : Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
        fields : fnDefineReqListData()
    }),
    columns : fnDefineReqListColumn()
    scroll : true,
    layout : 'fit',
    autoScroll : true,
    viewConfig : {
        stripeRows : false
    },
    disableSelection : true,
    listeners : {

        sortchange : function(thisGrid, sortinfo) {

            var grid = Ext.getCmp("Panel");
            /*
             * grid.store.sort(storeSorter); return;
             */
            var sorter = grid.store.sorters.getAt(0);
            var sort = sorter.property;
            var dir = sorter.direction;
             **// sorter.direction here always return ASC**

                 grid.store.sort({
                        sorterFn : sortingDate,
                        direction : dir
                    });

        }
});
```

Comment: share a fiddle reproducing the issue and correct the syntax errors..

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2vfv&view/editor

Comment: I think you can try to use array.reverse()

Comment: @Kanow  for sorting?

Comment: After you sort an array you can use this method to change the direction orand example you sorted it descending so if you use this method it will change into ascending( It will reverse your array so first element will be last, last will be first )

Answer (score 1):

While manual sort, you should persist the direction and toggle it. It will resolve the issue.

For sample fiddle I have used `sessionStorage`, if you want you can use configs to store the direction and toggle it.

```
sessionStorage.sortState = sessionStorage.sortState === 'ASC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';

grid.store.sort({
    sorterFn : sorting,
    direction : sessionStorage.sortState
});
```

You can find the working fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2vg0)

Comment: it only works when i click the header , but when i click the shorting icon in the menu to sort , the sorting is not correct